# Epimorphism from $F_2$ to the symmetric group $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Give an epimorphism from $F_2$ to the symmetric group $S_3$, and
>   determine the kernel $K$ of the epimorphism, and the rank of the free
>   group $K$.

So I need to find a surjective homomorphism from $F_2$ to $S_3$. The best I could come up with is a homomorphism from $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_2) \rightarrow $ permutations of non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^2$. This is surjective because the order of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_2)=$ order of $S_3=6$.

However, this is not what I'm being asked to find. What's an example of an epimorphism from $F_2$ to the symmetric group $S_3$?

Answer (score 3):

$F_2$ is freely generated by two things. Constructing a homomorphism $F_2\to G$ amounts to simply picking where those two generators go. There are no restrictions on where they can go in general, so it's the same as picking any two elements of $G$. If you want a surjection, though, you'll want to send generators to generators.

Here, you want to find two permutations in $S_3$ that generate it. Then you'll need to calculate the kernel of the homomorphism, in other words a minimal set of relations your chosen pair generators of $S_3$ satisfy...

Comment: Okay so how about $(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2) \in S_3$? So $\{0\} \in F_2 \rightarrow (1, 2, 3)$ and $\{1\} \in F_2 \rightarrow (1, 3, 2)$?

Comment: Nope. First off, I wouldn't write things like $\{0\}\in F_2$. Name your generators of $F_2$ something like $a$ and $b$. Secondly, the cycles $(123)$ and $(132)$ don't generate $S_3$, they generate a proper cyclic subgroup of order three inside $S_3$. You need to find two permutations that generate $S_3$.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay well $\{(1, 2), (2, 3)\}$ and $\{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)\}$ generate $S_3$. So $a \in F_2 \rightarrow \{(1, 2), (2, 3)\}$ and $b \in F_2 \rightarrow \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)\}$?

Comment: That makes no sense. How is $\{(12),(23)\}$ a permutation? That seems to be a set of two permutations. Do you understand what's going on? Maybe take some time to review everything you know and understand about the question and my answer then try again.

Comment: When you say find two permutations in $S_3$ that generate 'it', you mean that generate $S_3$, correct? So $(123)$ and $(12)$ should work.

Comment: Correct. So have your homomorphism send $a\mapsto(123)$ and $b\mapsto(12)$. Then, for instance, $ab^2a$ would be sent to $(123)(12)^2(123)=(132)$. Now you need to figure out the kernel, i.e. figure out what relations $(12)$ and $(123)$ satisfy.